# How can i add smoke to my particles?

Tags: particles

i added a quick smoke to all of my particles but theres no smoke on the particles. Why? Ive been trying different ways for 4 days and cant figure it out. I made all the quick smokes have replay cache. and i make my particle system have "whole collection

Answer (score 0):

First, select an object and add quick smoke. Now go to the physics tab of the flow object
-> settings -> Flow source -> change flow source from mesh to particle system then choose your particle system

1> Add particle system 
[image]

2> change flow source
[image]

3> bake all under cache
[image]

Comment: if you found it useful, please hit the tick mark beside the answer to help others facing the same issue.